# SAPUI5 filter Table dynamically on initialization with odata v4

Tags: odata, sapui5, odata-v4

I created a view in sap hana that I expose using odata v4 and this part is working well.

Now I'm trying to add a table in the details page of a worklist using the data from my view filtered by the ID of the object I display in the details page.

What I have tried so far is to do in directly in XML by doing that :

```
<Table  id="historyTable"
    inset="false"
    items="{
        path: '/wfl_comment',
        parameters : {
            $filter: 'INSTANCE_ID eq ${ID}'
        }
    }">
```

But as I found in SAPUI5 documentation it's not possible to do it dynamically in the XML.

So I tried to filter in the controller following this [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/5338bd1f9afb45fb8b2af957c3530e8f) and this [sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4.04/code) from SAPUI5 by adapting `onSearch` function of the sample in my `onInit` function.

My XML:

```
<Table  id="historyTable"
        inset="false"
        items="{
            path: '/wfl_comment'
        }">
```

My controller.js

```
onInit : function () {
    var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
            busy : true,
            delay : 0,
            synchronizationMode : "None"
        });
    this.getRouter().getRoute("object").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
    this.setModel(oViewModel, "objectView");
            
    let oView = this.getView();

    let sValue = oView.byId("ID").getValue();

    let oFilter = new Filter("INSTANCE_ID", FilterOperator.EQ, sValue);

    oView.byId("historyTable").getBinding("items").filter(oFilter, FilterType.Application);
}
```

Here because of the instantiation of `oFilter` I get the following error :

`The following error occurred while displaying routing target with name 'object': Error: Synchronization mode must be 'None' -`

But in my manifest.json I set Synchronization mode to None. Here is the models:

```
"models": {
    "i18n": {
        ...
        }
    },
    "": {
        "dataSource": "mainService",
        "preload": true,
        "settings": {
            "operationMode": "Server",
            "groupId": "$direct",
            "synchronizationMode": "None",
            "autoExpandSelect":true
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to set a static value instead of `sValue` when I instantiate `oFilter` but it's not working either.

How can I fix this error ? and is it the right way to filter the data for a Table that I only want to filter once during the initialization ?

Comment: add a router. bind your view after the router matched as it is in every example in the www